# RSA Key Issues when Trying to Make RDP Connection on AWS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, rsa, rdp

I have a private RSA key generated for my AWS EC2 instance. This key was generated through the AWS web interface. I have it saved in a file folder. When attempting to upload it to generate a password for an RDP connection the file folder in which it is in appears blank as if there is nothing in the folder. It is a .pkk file, which must be compatible with everything as this very file was generated via their own web interface

Because I can not upload the file I sought to copy and paste the key into the window on their web interface for this purpose. I opened the key with PuttyGen.

It is in the format

ssh-rsa
hkdsbghkdbhvkbfsvhkfdbngjkdfnbjkfbnjdsfhbhfsg
name

The name being what I named the key when I created it. When I copy and paste it into their web interface and try to generate a password it tells me it must begin with -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and end with -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----. I am familiar with this from other encryption software; sometimes those lines are excluded and you can simply type them in and the key will work. I have tried typing them in both before and after the ssh-rsa and name; as well as deleting the ssh-rsa and name. I always get "Error decrypting key...make sure the key is correct."

Does anyone have any ideas why the file folder appears empty when I try to upload or what syntax I need to use to make the key readable?

There is a fingerprint for the key; SHA256:etc. Does this need to be placed anywhere for the key to read properly?

Comment: *...which must be compatible with everything as this very file was generated via their own web interface ...* Wishful thinking. SSH uses different formats than other standards.

Comment: When you created the keypair, you can either download the OpenSSH or PuTTY version of the private key.  The online tool to decrypt the password for Windows images can only use the OpenSSH version of the key.  Either generate a new key and use the OpenSSH version, or use "puttygen" to load the ppk file and export it as an OpenSSH format.